# How do I turn a byte-formatted Python string into bytes?

Tags: python, types, casting

I'm currently working on a Python program that necessitates the conversion of an object from the string to bytes datatype back and forth. As of present, my string data looks like this:

**<class 'str'>** `b'\xa1\xc9\x1c\xe29\xc5]\x02\xaerZ\xfaC'`

Because the string is already formatted in bytes format, attempting to turn it into a bytes datatype is problematic, because the encode() function will almost immediately attempt to format it again, resulting in:

**<class 'bytes'>** `b"b'\\xa1\\xc9\\x1c\\xe29\\xc5]\\x02\\xaerZ\\xfaC'"`

When what I'm looking for is:

**<class 'bytes'>** `b'\xa1\xc9\x1c\xe29\xc5]\x02\xaerZ\xfaC'`

Is there any way to cast the object from a string into bytes without having it format my data?

Comment: Don't produce such a string in the first place?

Comment: can you post steps to create such a string?

Comment: Maybe use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it since you seem to have a string containing a bytes literal.

Comment: John, using eval/literal_eval() works wonderfully! Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your interpretation here.

If your string is already `b'\xa1\xc9\x1c\xe29\xc5]\x02\xaerZ\xfaC'`, then that is a bytes object.

Try this in IDLE:

```
x = b'\xa1\xc9\x1c\xe29\xc5]\x02\xaerZ\xfaC'
print(type(x))
```

You will get `<class 'bytes'>`

Is your string already `"b'\xa1\xc9\x1c\xe29\xc5]\x02\xaerZ\xfaC'"`?

In that case, how did it get that way?  You probably used str without an encoding parameter.  That is kind of a bad idea.

You can get back the original with eval().  But that is considered very bad style.  Unless you have a lot of control over your source of data, people could theoretically fake out your source and execute the equivalent of SQL-injection only with Python code.

```
eval("b'\xa1\xc9\x1c\xe29\xc5]\x02\xaerZ\xfaC'")
```

will return the bytes object:

```
b'\xa1\xc9\x1c\xe29\xc5]\x02\xaerZ\xfaC'
```

Otherwise, since you already formatted it 'as repr' by calling str() on it, you will need to actually *parse it*.  That is not hard, but just confusing as all get out.

You could start with `re.findall(r"(\\x..)|(.+?)", s)` to get your binary and your text data into different 'piles'

Throw away the first two and the last one, so the s should be `s[2:-1]`

Then each text part needs to be encoded by something like: `bytes(text, 'ascii')`

And each hex part needs to be reconverted into a character code by something like: `bytes([int(binary[-2:], 16)])`

And these need to be strung back together with something like: `b''.join()`

For an overall mess like this:

```
b''.join([bytes(text, 'ascii') or bytes([int(binary[-2:], 16)])
    for binary, text in re.findall(r"(\\x..)|(.+?)", y[2:-1])])
```

Now, this works.  But it would be far better to convert the binary into a string *with an encoding*, something like utf8, that can handle arbitrary character codes, and then decode it with the same one.  See if you can get the person sending this on to you to convert it properly to begin with.